# could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scalaz.Applicative

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to reduce this code (scalaz 7.0.x, scala 2.10.x):

```
type Error[+A] = \/[String, A]
type Result[+A] = OptionT[Error, A]
```

into this:

```
type Result[+A] = OptionT[({ type λ[+α] = String \/ α })#λ, A]
```

And I got error "could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scalaz.Applicative[Main.Result]" for:

```
val result: Result[Int] = 42.point[Result]
```

Why reduced code doesn't look like the first example for scalac?

Comment: It seems pretty likely you're seeing [this bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6895) (although I could have sworn I've written exactly this code before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit resolution of lambda types seems broken. Apparently the compiler first desugars the the type and then mismatches on the number of type parameters.

A 'simplified' example:

Defining a monad and two traits. `One` is similar to `Either`. `Two` is similar to `EitherT`

```
trait Monad[F[_]]

trait One[A, B]
object One {
  implicit def m[A]: Monad[({ type T[x] = One[A, x] })#T] = ???
}
trait Two[F[_], A]
object Two {
  implicit def m[F[_]]: Monad[({ type T[x] = Two[F, x] })#T] = ???
}
```

Defining a type alias and a case class to partially apply `One` with `String` as it's first parameter. The case class version can be used as a workaround.

```
type OneX[A] = One[String, A]
case class OneY[A](value: OneX[A])
object OneY {
  implicit def m(implicit ev: Monad[OneX]): Monad[OneY] = ???
}
```

Implicit resolution of all 'simple' types works.

```
implicitly[Monad[OneX]]
implicitly[Monad[({ type T[x] = One[String, x] })#T]]
implicitly[Monad[OneY]]
```

Defining several type aliases that partially apply `Two`

```
type TwoX[A] = Two[OneX, A]
type TwoY[A] = Two[({ type T[x] = One[String, x] })#T, A]
type TwoZ[A] = Two[OneY, A]
```

Here we see that the one using the lambda type fails.

```
implicitly[Monad[TwoX]]
implicitly[Monad[TwoY]] // fails
implicitly[Monad[TwoZ]]
```

Here we see that all lambda types that use a type alias fail. Only the one that actually refers to a stable type with a single parameter succeeds.

```
implicitly[Monad[({ type T[x] = Two[OneX, x] })#T]] // fails
implicitly[Monad[({ type T[x] = Two[OneY, x] })#T]]
implicitly[Monad[({ type T[x] = Two[({ type T[x] = One[String, x] })#T, x] })#T]] //fails
```

My knowledge about the compiler is fairly limited and this might be related to the bug @TravisBrown points to.